# Building a simulation model for IoT device

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data-science-model

I have an IoT device that takes inputs in bytes and returns the output in bytes; My goal is to build a software simulator for the IoT device.

Some example inputs & outputs:

```
Input:  [50, 10, 40, 20, 7, 30, 0]  # here 7 is length of packet, 30 is command, 0 is status
Output: [40, 20, 50, 10, 7, 31, 1]  # here 7 is length of packet, 31 is command, 1 is status

Input:  [50, 10, 40, 20, 8, 35, 0, 5] # 5 register read
Output: [40, 20, 50, 10, 12, 36, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Input:  [50, 10, 40, 20, 8, 35, 0, 2] # 2 register read
Output: [40, 20, 50, 10, 12, 36, 1, 1, 2]

Input:  [50, 10, 40, 20, 8, 40, 0] # this is example of streaming sensor data
Output: [40, 20, 50, 10, 8, 41, 100]
Output: [40, 20, 50, 10, 8, 41, 101]
Output: [40, 20, 50, 10, 8, 41, 102]
Output: [40, 20, 50, 10, 8, 41, 103]
Output: [40, 20, 50, 10, 8, 41, 104]
```

Is there any existing solution I can use, or can you point me in the direction of solving such problems or any similar solution (any similar machine learning solution)? I have read about process discovery, but I am not sure if that will be of much help.

Thank you.

Comment: Simpy is good for simulations.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the IoT device's application field.

If the IoT device follows a simple process, easy to follow, you can generate data artificially with some known rules.

However, if the environment is more complex, like depending on a 3D environment, you will want to simulate such an environment. Some companies use [digital twins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_twin) to simulate a complete environment properly. Some other simulate physical events with python libraries (ex: [thermodynamics](https://pypi.org/project/thermopy/)) or tools like [MatLab](https://fr.mathworks.com/products/simulink.html) or [Labview](https://www.ni.com/en-us/solutions/design-prototype.html).

I would need more information about the process you want to simulate to give advice about the right libraries and tools.

Comment: Does it answer your question? If not, please let me know.